# Derivative of the Logarithm - Dirac

Tags: logarithms, dirac-delta

So I stumbled across P.Dirac's book Principles of Quantum Mechanics and I found something really peculiar on page 61 of the Fourth Edition.

He states that usually we accept that $$\frac{d}{dx}\log(x)=\frac
{1}{x}$$ for real positive x.

However the author states that it can be extended to $$\frac{d}{dx}\log(x)=\frac
{1}{x}-i\pi\delta(x)$$

He argues the following way:
\begin{equation}
\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{d}{dx} \log(x)\,dx=\int_{-a}^{a}\frac{1}{x}-i\pi\delta(x)dx
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\log(-1)=-i\pi \bigg| \exp(.)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
e^{\log(-1)}=e^{-i\pi}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
-1=e^{-i\pi}
\end{equation}

Intuitively I think it has to do with Riemann surfaces and I think one could somehow using this extend the definition of complex exponentials and write them the following way:
\begin{equation}
e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)+\hat{j}m
\end{equation}
Where m indicates the mth Riemann surface and j is kind of a vector basis.
$$m=(\theta-\text{mod}_{2\pi}(\theta))/2\pi$$

Comment: What do you actually want to know?

Comment: I would guess the question here is:  the formulas Dirac writes are wrong in mathematics as conventionally understood.  Is there a way to make sense of them in terms of conventional mathematics, perhaps one that involves Riemann surfaces?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/127601/does-the-derivative-of-log-have-a-dirac-delta-term

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We will define the distribution $\frac{d\log(x)}{dx}$ through the regularization given by

$$\frac{d\log(x)}{dx} \sim \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\left(\frac{d\log(x+i\epsilon)}{dx}\right)$$

Then, for any $a<0<b$ and smooth test function $\phi(x)$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_a^b \frac{d\log(x)}{dx}\phi(x)\,dx&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_a^b \left(\frac{d\log(x+i\epsilon)}{dx}\right)\phi(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_a^b\left(\frac{1}{x+i\epsilon}\right)\phi(x)\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\left(\int_a^b\left(\frac{x}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\right)\phi(x)\,dx-i\int_a^b \left(\frac{\epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\right)\phi(x)\,dx\right)\\\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\left(\int_a^b\left(\frac{x}{x^2+\epsilon^2}\right)\phi(x)\,dx\right)-i\pi \phi(0)\\\\
&=PV\left(\int_a^b \frac{\phi(x)}{x}\,dx\right)-i\pi \phi(0)
\end{align}$$

where $PV$ denotes the Principal Value of the integral.

Therefore, we find that in distribution

$$\frac{d\log(x)}{dx}\sim PV\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-i\pi \delta(x)$$

---

Alternatively, let $\psi$ be the ditribution $\psi(x)=\left(\log(x)\right)$.  Then, we can write for any $\phi\in C_C^\infty$

$$\langle \psi',\phi\rangle = - \langle \psi, \phi'\rangle$$

Hence, we have

$$\begin{align}
-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \log(x)\phi'(x)\,dx&=-\int_{-\infty}^0 (\log(|x|)+i\pi)\phi'(x)\,dx-\int_0^\infty \log(x)\phi'(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-i\pi \phi(0)-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \log(|x|)\phi'(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-i\pi \phi(0)-\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\int_{|x|\ge\delta} \log(|x|)\phi'(x)\,dx\\\\
&=-i\pi \phi(0)+\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\int_{|x|\ge\delta}\frac{\phi(x)}{x}\,dx\\\\
&=-i\pi \phi(0)+\text{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\phi(x)}{x}\,dx\\\\
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we find that in distribution

$$\frac{d}{dx}\log(x)=\text{PV}\left(\frac1x\right)-i\pi \delta(x)$$

as expected!